# How do you configure IntelliJ IDEA to place the cursor in the editor window after hitting enter on a file in the project window?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I'm big on not using the mouse, especially while writing code.  I've noticed in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 that when I'm navigating in the project window, hitting `Enter` while a particular file is selected opens the file in an editor, but it doesn't place the cursor in the editor.  Interestingly, if I double-click on the file in the project window, the cursor *is* placed in the editor.

How do I configure IntelliJ to place the cursor in the editor after opening the file via `Enter` from the project window?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, I do not believe there is a way to configure what you are looking for. A search for `focus` in the settings didn't turn up anything.

That said, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> when in the project view will return you to the editor. So you would need to do <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If having to type two keys in a row bothers you, you could always record a macro (*Edit > Macros*) to do that key sequence and map it to a shortcut.